# SOAP-UI - How to pass data from CSV to xml inside parameter as request

Tags: xml, csv, groovy, soapui

I wrote the groovy script ready:

```
context.fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader('C:/abc.csv'))

rowsData = context.fileReader.readLines()
int rowsize = rowsData.size()

for(int i =0;  i < rowsize;  i++)
{

    rowdata = rowsData[i]
    String[] propData = rowdata.split(",")
    curTC = testRunner.testCase
    curTC.setPropertyValue("data1",propData[0])
    curTC.setPropertyValue("data2",propData[1])
    curTC.getTestStepAt(0).setName("data1-" + propData[1])
    curTC.getTestStepAt(1).setName("data2-" + propData[0])

    testRunner.gotoStep(0)
    testRunner.gotoStep(1)
}
```

Trying to take data 1 and data 2 put in XML parameter, so I can parametrize the test data request.

Answer (score 0):

Your script sets testCase properties ... with `curTC.setPropertyValue...`. You should be able to just use those inline in your request, using `${#TestCase#data1}` and `${#TestCase#data2}`.

See [official documentation](http://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/property-expansion.html) for more information.

Comment: <req:data1 input="${#testcase#data1}"/>
            <req:data1 input="$(#testcase#data2}" />    it is not working

Comment: Note the capitalization of "TestCase" ... it's important.

Comment: i mean yeah it was cap, when i copy i wrote lower, still not working

Comment: i even tried this <req:data1 input=>${#testcase#data1}<req:data1 input=>

Comment: Does the testcase property tab show the correct information?

Comment: Yep it worked i put Testcase C as lower, my bad, but when i put contain assertions for data1, its say missing token

Comment: i put <data1>${#TestCase#data1}<data1/>, its says missing token

Comment: That sounds like a new problem! What is "it" in this case? What does your assertion look like?

Comment: its a contain Assertion  i put <data1>${#TestCase#data1}<data1/>, its says missing token

Comment: Maybe you should look for `...</data1>`? Note the placement of the slash!

Comment: Can we get this done using loop thru XL file with column name and and rows, would you mind explain how we can import from XL and export?

Comment: Not in a 600-character comment!

Comment: Would you email me?, if you can do that i will be really appriciated